# How to fix the behavior of this wijmo popup when I update an *ngIf condition

Tags: angular, popupwindow, wijmo

I have wijmo popup with some content inside, there is a ng-container with a *ngIf condition that if evaluates to true shows X and else show the ng-template. The problem is that if I update the condition inside the ng-container to show the else statement, this causes to close the wijmo popup(else statement is shown rapidly before closure).

If I update the condition outside the ng-container(still inside wijmo popup) the behavior is correct. I tried the same code outside a wijmo popup and the behavior is correct.

```
<wj-popup id="wj_popup_1 [modal]="true">
   <ng-container *ngIf="!estListeTropLongue; else messageListeTropLong">
      <button (click)="estListeTropLongue = true"></button>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-template #messageListeTropLong>
      <div class="message-liste-trop-long">Veuillez saisir des caractères pour 
      lancer la recherche</div>
   </ng-template>
</wj-popup>
```

The wijmo popup shouldn't close and show the ng-template information but the popup closes without any console error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could set the hide trigger of the wijmo popup to 'None';

```
<wj-popup id="wj_popup_1 [modal]="true" [hideTrigger]="None">
   <ng-container *ngIf="!estListeTropLongue; else messageListeTropLong">
      <button (click)="estListeTropLongue = true"></button>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-template #messageListeTropLong>
      <div class="message-liste-trop-long">Veuillez saisir des caractères pour 
      lancer la recherche</div>
   </ng-template>
</wj-popup>
```